# Centering Text Horizontally and Vertically in LaTeX

Tags: latex, tabular, centering

I would like to produce the following:

```
      a       b
    xxxxx   xxxxx
 1  xxxxx   xxxxx
    xxxxx   xxxxx

    xxxxx   xxxxx
 2  xxxxx   xxxxx
    xxxxx   xxxxx
```

Where the blocks of 'x's are images, and 'a', 'b', '1' and '2' are text.

Here are my two attempts so far:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
 & a & b \\
1 & \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.47\textwidth]{im.png}} &
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.47\textwidth]{im.png}} \\
2 & \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.47\textwidth]{im.png}} &
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.47\textwidth]{im.png}} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Which produces:

```
      a       b
    xxxxx   xxxxx
    xxxxx   xxxxx
 1  xxxxx   xxxxx

    xxxxx   xxxxx
    xxxxx   xxxxx
 2  xxxxx   xxxxx
```

And

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{m{1cm}m{6cm}m{6cm}}
 & a & b \\
1 & \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.47\textwidth]{im.png}} &
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.47\textwidth]{im.png}} \\
2 & \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.47\textwidth]{im.png}} &
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.47\textwidth]{im.png}} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Which produces:

```
    a       b
    xxxxx   xxxxx
 1  xxxxx   xxxxx
    xxxxx   xxxxx

    xxxxx   xxxxx
 2  xxxxx   xxxxx
    xxxxx   xxxxx
```

Comment: For future readers, please check: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12703/how-to-create-fixed-width-table-columns-with-text-raggedright-centered-raggedlef

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can make a new column type, or simply add `>{\centering\arraybackslash}` before `m{6cm}` for the two image columns.

For example:

```
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash} m{6cm} }  %# New column type
\begin{tabular}{m{1cm}CC}                                %# Table with two of them
...
```

The `>` directive lets you basically inject the contained code before each entry in that column. We need the `\arraybackslash` to deal with incompatibility between the `centering` environment and the `tabular` environment. <strike>[More info can be found here.]</strike> [1](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=tabcellalign)

Answer (score 4):

I use `\dummyimage`, because I have no `im.png`.  Replace it with `\includegraphics{im.png}`.

```
\font\dummyfont = cmr10 at 100pt
\def\dummyimage{{\vbox to 100pt{\vfil\hbox to 100pt{\hfil\dummyfont A\hfil}\vfil}}}

\hfil\vbox{
\halign{&\hfil\ $\vcenter{\hbox{#}}$\strut \ \hfil\cr
&a&b\cr 
1&\dummyimage&\dummyimage\cr
2&\dummyimage&\dummyimage\cr
}}
```

Comment: @Svante: Yes.  I don't see anything in Alexey's answer that would cause problems in Latex.